What did Wittgenstein mean by ”contradiction is the outer limit of propositions”?
I’ve been working my way through Wittgenstein’s Tractatus, and have been stuck on 5.143 all day. In full, the comment states:
“Contradiction is that common factor of propositions which no proposition has in common with another. Tautology is the common factor of all propositions that have nothing in common with one another.
Contradiction, one might say, vanishes outside all propositions: tautology vanishes inside them.
Contradiction is the outer limit of propositions: tautology is the unsubstantial point at their centre.”
According to Black’s guide, the passage seems to have something to do with any proposition p having itself in common with any stronger proposition p•q (• == ‘and’). That statement makes sense to me, insofar as the truth grounds of p are equal to itself, the truth-grounds of p•q are likewise equal, and that since p =/= p•q, p•q is stronger than p. What I don’t then understand is Black’s argument that this is shown by p + p•q (+ == ‘or’) equaling p, and that “in order to get a proposition 'which no proposition has in common with another' we would have to take successively stronger propositions.” Wouldn’t taking successfully stronger propositions mean the opposite, since p•q•r would have p and r in common, p•q•r•s p,r, and s in common, and so on? I know I’m misunderstanding some fundamental point here, so I’d really appreciate some help.

Wittgenstein's wording is not at all clear, and Black's exposition is only a little better. When Black says that we would have to take successively stronger propositions, he is referring to the common component between two given propositions. It is the p in his first formula.
Let's backtrack and explain it a different way.
Following Black, we might understand two propositions as having something in common if there is some proposition that is the logical consequence of both. So the conjunctions p ∧ q and p ∧ r have the common component p, since both entail p.
So, what would have to be true for two propositions to have nothing in common? Minimally, the only thing that follows from any arbitrary choice of q and r is a tautology, since by the principle of implosion a tautology is the logical consequence of any proposition whatever. This appears to be the sense in which Wittgenstein says, "Tautology is the common factor of all propositions that have nothing in common with one another." So q and r have nothing in common if tautologies are their only shared logical consequence.
But by the principle of explosion, any q and r would have all their logical consequences in common if q and r have a contradiction in common. This seems to be the sense in which Wittgenstein says, "Contradiction is that common factor of propositions which no proposition has in common with another".
As to what Wittgenstein means by "the outer limit of propositions" I'm not sure. Maybe it is something like this. Suppose we think of propositions as containing information. A tautology is empty: it contains no information. A logically contingent proposition contains some information. A contradiction represents the maximum amount of information a proposition could possibly contain. In fact it contains so much information that it is inconsistent and useless.
This is a rather crude way of expressing how propositions work, though it does seem to fit with what Wittgenstein says in 5.14, "If one proposition follows from another, then the latter says more than the former". The idea seems to be that logical consequence is a relation that holds between a stronger proposition and a weaker one. At one extreme we have tautologies, which are maximally weak and are entailed by anything. At the other extreme we have contradictions, which are maximally strong and entail anything.

+1  Worth adding that considering propositions as ordered by implication this way (so as you say, tautology is the greatest element and contradiction is the least, or vice versa depending on which way round you put the order) turns out to be surprisingly powerful, and is a fundamental construction in mathematical logic — it gives a Boolean algebra, the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of a language or theory, and can be seen as an algebraic embodiment of the theory.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I was about to say "boolean aldebra": The infimum of P and Q is P∧Q, the supremum is P∨Q. In analogy to {+,Σ} if we go to the "Σ-version" of ∧ and "sum" the whole algebra we get F (contradiction) if we do it likewise with ∨ we get T (tautology). The ordering relation of the boolean algebra is ⇒ .

I feel like I’ve gotten a clearer sense of what Wittgenstein is getting at in this passage, although his phrasing in the first paragraph is still confusing, and I don’t know whether Black’s interpretation really gels with my own. Basically, since a contradiction has no truth grounds, and since a proposition which shares the same truth grounds as another follows from it, all propositions follow from any contradiction. IE (FFF…F)(p) leads to any proposition q, since q won’t have a false conclusion where there is a true conclusion in p (since p has no true conclusion). Similarly, a tautology q follows from any proposition p, since q won’t have a false conclusion where there is a true conclusion in p (since q is true anywhere where p is true).

The "boundary" for Wittgenstein here, I believe, is the boundary of thought one has once one accepts a conclusion.  A contradiction can't be accepted in this manner (the brain doesn't allow it into it`s framework to preserve, presumably, the order of its contents).
Therefore, a contradiction is (at) the boundary of a proposition.
